# How to prove that the determinant is the same no matter how you take it?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

To find the determinant, pick a row and move along it creating minors and use the recursive definition of determinant. 
How do we know that the determinant will be the same no matter which row you pick to do this process?

Comment: By comparing to Leibniz's formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants).

Comment: In each case we have the same sum of products of elements $a_{i,\sigma(i)}$ where $\sigma$ runs on $S_n$, and take negative sign if the permutation is odd.